# How do I link c++ code against "libguile" with "guile-1.8.8"?

Tags: c++, ld, guile

I want to embed guile in a c++ application, but I get "undefined reference" errors when I try to compile:
Ubuntu 12.04
guile-1.8.8

If I compile the example from the [guile docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/docs/docs-1.8/guile-ref/A-Sample-Guile-Main-Program.html#A-Sample-Guile-Main-Program)

```
gcc -o guile-test `pkg-config guile-1.8 --cflags` `pkg-config guile-1.8 --libs` guile-test.c
```

on the console, it aborts with errors:

```
/tmp/ccHZCHNL.o: In function `inner_main':
guile-test.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `scm_shell'
/tmp/ccHZCHNL.o: In function `main':
guile-test.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `scm_boot_guile'
collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
```

If I compile some *example.so* (including "libguile.h") to embed in guile, all is working as expected.

Does anybody know, what might cause this error?

Best, Jan-Peter

Comment: Note that I would very highly recommend moving to Guile 2.x - it's both considerably faster and has much more reliable string handling in the C interface (with `scm_from_utf8_string()` etc.)

Comment: I would think of it, but I am waiting for lilypond moving to guile 2, which is hopefully going to happen this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You didn't follow their build instructions correctly. :-) In particular, you need to specify link dependencies *after* the dependent objects. Try this instead:

```sh
gcc -o guile-test `pkg-config guile-1.8 --cflags` guile-test.c `pkg-config guile-1.8 --libs`
```

In particular, the libraries need to be listed *after* all the objects that use them, such as `guile-test.c`.

(By the way, this isn't Guile-specific. The standard linker always expects this ordering.)